# MYSQL error while trying to connect wordpress database

Tags: mysql

When I connect to my WordPress site in a browser, I see this:

[image: Error Establishing a Database Connection]

When I check on the status of MySQL in Terminal, I see this:

```
sudo systemctl status mysql

● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server

   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-04-30 11:17:39 IST; 2s ago
  Process: 9424 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

sr: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
sr: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
sr: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
sr: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
sr: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
sr: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
sr: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
sr: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
sr: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You should see a more specific reason for the MySQL error in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`. Could you check that file and [edit] your question to include the most relevant lines?

Answer (score 0):

this is because of incorrect details entered in wp-config.php

when i corrected the database username in sudo nano /var/www/html/wp-config.php it working now